# :before not used for table in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with the placement of a table under Firefox. The code works fine under chrome and safari.

A "live" version of the problem can be [seen here](http://sandsynligvis.dk/2018/06/14/hvem-vinder-vm-2018-og-hvem-er-bedst-til-at-pr%C3%A6diktere-det/)  but the picture below shows the problem.

[image]

The start/end of the html code that inserts the table is shown below, and that is a standard html table

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th align="left">Navn</th>
<th align="left">Gruppe</th>
<th align="right">odds</th>
<th align="right">ELO</th>
<th></th>
....
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The problem arises with the margin/width definition in the css. The relevant code is shown below

```
table, table.booktabs {
   /* making booktabs style tables the unstyled default in case someone uses Markdown styling  */
   width: auto;
   margin: auto;
   border-spacing: 0px;
   border-top: 2px solid #333;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
```

If the margin or width is tweaked then the width and placement of the table is tweaked but the column part of the layout is not preserved. The width of the left column (and hence the table) is set before the table using

```
table:before {
   width: 61%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

but that piece of code has *no* effect under firefox, so the width of `width: 61%;` is never set. Can someone tell me why and give alternative solutions that will work across browsers? Oh, and it's the same with `::before`.

Comment: to use :before you must set `content:""`

Comment: _“The width of the left column (and hence the table) is set before the table using `table:before`”_ - sounds to me like that might be the main mistake/flaw here to begin with. `:before` renders is if you inserted a new child element at the beginning of the element. Using _that_ to make the table itself move into the desired position, is what I would call an _abuse_ of the technology here … Pretty sure there’s different solutions to this problem - whatever that problem actually is to begin with, because removing the pseudo element leaves your live example looking pretty much the same in Chrome.

Comment: @CBroe that could very well be true. My problem is that setting the `width` of the table forces with width of the actual table and not the width of the container. Possibly that should be set differently in css, but that doesn't really answer why the results are different. Possibly `:before` should not be used with `table` in the first place and firefox just adheres to this.

Comment: _“My problem is that setting the width of the table forces with width of the actual table and not the width of the container.”_ – that sounds like what anyone would expect to happen, not sure why you’d consider that a “problem.” (It might not _achieve_ what you want - but that brings us right back to that you failed to actually explain that in the first place.)

Comment: _“Possibly :before should not be used with table”_ - the point I was trying to make by mentioning that it behaves like an actual child element, so in that case that could only be a tbody or maybe thead. You would not use the actual versions of those elements to try and change the alignment of your table, so using a pseudo equivalent doesn’t make much sense here either IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `pseudo` like `:before` you must set `content` 
For example:

```
table:before {
   content:"";
   width: 61%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Learn here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: tel me if it helps you

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything when the `content: "";` is added.

Comment: you will see it in style(f12) then style as you want it

Comment: without content you dont see :before in f12 and nothing happend

Comment: True, but nothing I enter in `:before` has any impact on the table.

Comment: you want space after table??? use `:after` with `display:block` and set `width` you have to set `poistion:absolute`